# PHP strategy to let proxies cache pages only when user is not logged in

Tags: php, browser-cache, cache-control

Assume I have a Blog, since there's some costly PHP code running behind I want its pages allowed to be cached by HTTP headers (by users' browsers or intermediate proxies), that's fine as long the user is not logged in, however I want that when he log in the cache is by-passed in some way so that he sees the most up-to-date content.

The landing page may have a "login box", so when he effectively do the login the "login box" is not showed again, instead I want to see a nice message "Hi UserX, current time is DD:MM:YYYY".

The whole page is considered static as long as the user is not logged in, however I want the same page considered dynamic when the user do the login. Does exists any simple way to achieve that?

Comment: the simplest is a different page for logged in users. Once the browser has cached a page, its actually not possible to get the page to update before the date set. But as a alternative, have you thought about serving a static page  and set headers to no-cache? You still have the overhead of a php function to include the file but you can update it at will. Or check out object caching.

Comment: I already do caching on server-side using Twig. I wanted to do that also on client (and intermediate proxies) side to reduce pressure for a content based service. so basically I need to put in form action  `index.php?logged=true` so that I get again to the same page but with a different link.

Comment: yes but now that page is cached....you can change headers using php but not if you set them using a higher level, i.e. apache/nginx, htaccess.

Comment: Same PHP script, if accessed with `?logged=true` it sets haders for no caching, if accessed without that piece of url it provide headers that enable caching. From browser point of view those would be 2 different pages, the cached version always points to non-cached version from each login box, loggin out points to cached version. I would starts with a 10 minutes cache, and eventually extend caching time if server pressure is just too high. that's how I interpreted your comments :)

Comment: cool..just to give you a heads up, if you are interested in server efficiency, copy the rendered page html and set up a new server with nginx and save as a html file. Set nginx to pre-compress files. Use jmeter to test your 2 servers. The compressed one will leave the php server for dust...a 1gb linode vps can serve 270 ish concurrent users with a compressed file 20kb, at the lower end of the scale, the same server with apache+php+mysql + wordpress = 4 concurrent users.

Comment: or setup apache with spdy?

Comment: interesting now that nginx have dropped support for spdy in fav of http2, and i haven't used spdy but as far as i looked at it, it is more aimed at connections (i still use the http1 workarounds for this). But pre-compressing html files is complimentary to spdy/pagespeed modules. Pre-compressing means no processing power is used to compress on the demand if you get me. But benchmark yourself.